# Prove that $f(x)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $ f: [a, b] \to \Bbb {R} $ is continuous in $ [a, b] $, and there is a number $ \alpha \neq \beta $ such that $$ \alpha \int_a^c f ( x) \, dx + \beta \int_c^b f (x) \, dx = 0,$$ for all $ c \in (a, b) $. Prove that $f(x)=0$, for all $x\in[a,b]$.

For absurdity, suppose that $ f (x) \neq 0 $. So $ \alpha \int_a^c f (x) \, dx \neq 0 $, likewise with $ \beta \int_c^b f (x) \, dx \neq 0 $. Therefore, the sum of the integrals will be different from $ 0 $, but that contradicts the general hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

The question as phrased prior to the edit has a counterexample. For the corrected question, the answer is positive. The argument given by OP in the comments to this answer is correct. Basically, consider the sum of two integrals as a function of $c$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

---

The previous version of the question said $$\alpha \int_a^c f(x) dx + \beta \int_{b}^c f(x)dx \equiv 0.$$
Note the order of the variables for the integration domains. For this we have a counterexample:
Note that for all $c\in(0,2\pi)$, $$0=\int_0^{2\pi} \sin xdx=\int_0^{c}  \sin xdx + \int_c^{2\pi}  \sin xdx = \int_0^c \sin x dx - \int_{2\pi}^c  \sin xdx $$
Therefore $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a  continuous nonzero function on $[a,b]=[0,2\pi]$ such that $\alpha=1,\beta=-1\neq \alpha$ such that for all $c\in(0,2\pi)$,
$$\alpha \int_0^c f(x) dx + \beta \int_{2\pi}^c f(x)dx \equiv 0.$$

Comment: I guess you need to assume $\alpha \ne \beta$. Then if one defines $$g(x)=\alpha \int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx+\beta \int_{x}^{b}f(x) dx$$

then $g(c)=0$ for all $c \in [a,b]$. Thus $g$ is a constant and by fundamental theorem of calculus $g$ is differentiable. So $g'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Thus $(\alpha-\beta)(f(x))=0$...

Comment: Typo in the last integral at end. The limits of integral should be $2\pi,c$. Apart from that +1. This is the case when $\alpha+\beta=0$ which you discussed in comments to another answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thank you for the finding the typo.

Comment: @asdasd you should note that the second integral in your question says $\int_b^c$, not $\int_c^b$. Otherwise what you said is precisely koro's answer

Comment: I think the correct version of the question should be the one mentioned in the comment (by asker) to this answer. Request @asdasd to update their question if they think so.

Comment: I made a mistake in writing the exercise, now I have corrected it.

Comment: Amazing +1. I have deleted my answer. Why was FTC  not working in case of $\alpha = - \beta$?

Comment: @Koro thank you; the only reason I edited my answer to include the proof sketch is because yours was deleted. It doesn't work for $\alpha=-\beta\neq 0$ because in this case, the statement is actually a special case of the additivty of the integral over disjoint sets $\int_{A\cup B}f = \int_A f + \int_B f$, which is true. And there are many functions for which the total integral is just zero (sine being the first one I thought of)

Comment: (sorry, the explanation should go the other way round: FIRST there are many functions whose total integral is zero. THEN for any function like this, we have additivity over disjoint sets, which is just a funny way to write zero.)

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I see the question itself has changed now. I somehow misread the question and got confused. Considering the revised case, my earlier answer is correct. But let’s forget that and think about the case when second integral had limit from b to c (earlier version of this question), suppose that for some reason this counterexample of $\sin$ hadn’t occured to anybody, then  they would’ve proceeded with FTC may be! But FTC clearly failed! Why?

Comment: @Koro I was typing as if we were talking about this case, yes. FTC did not fail, it just doesn’t tell you anything because the same method just gives you $0=0$. Sine is not special, any function that has integral zero works (even those that are not continuous)

Comment: @Koro: rule of thumb: FTC never fails. If you think that it failed then search for some aspect which you might have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the direct proof.
First if f is continuous then is integrable on any closed sub interval of [a,b] and the result of integration is a real nonzero number.
In that case, we have a linear equation with nonzero real coefficients in the unknown $\alpha, \beta$ and infinitely many solutions.

The problem says that only a particular pair $\alpha, \beta)$ solves the linear equation. Therefore, the ratio of the coefficients is the negative reciprocal of the solution value pair. Which would render the ratio of the coefficients a constant.

The only way we could get a constant value no matter how we would divide the area is if the area was zero. Leading to f(x)=0.

This is the explanation. If you need help to write the solution let me know.